# Ошибка сегментации

Tags: gdb

```
#0  0x00007fb14f4836f0 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0000000000807eec in sema_wait (soap=0x7fb0e8002950,
    command=<value optimized out>, result=0x7fb0f61d4438)
    at /opt/libs/include/ace/OS_NS_Thread.inl:2016
No locals.
#2  acquire (soap=0x7fb0e8002950, command=<value optimized out>,
    result=0x7fb0f61d4438) at /opt/libs/include/ace/Semaphore.inl:31
No locals.
#3  ns1__executeCommand (soap=0x7fb0e8002950, command=<value optimized out>,
    result=0x7fb0f61d4438)
    at /TCSoap.cpp:104
        accountId = <value optimized out>
        connection = {pendingCommands = {semaphore_ = {sema_ = 0x0,
              name_ = 0x7fb0e802b110 "pendingCommands"}, removed_ = false},
          m_success = 147, m_printBuffer = ""}
        acc = <value optimized out>
        printBuffer = <value optimized out>
#4  0x000000000103f2dd in soap_serve_ns1__executeCommand (soap=0x7fb0e8002950)
    at /soapServer.cpp:76
        soap_tmp_ns1__executeCommand = {command = 0x7fb0e802a1d0 ".com"}
```

Прошу помочь решить проблемуь

Comment: Скорее всего вы где-то попортили стек.

Answer (score 1):

Полный лог по команде bt дайте. Еще полезно собирать программы с включенными опциями для отладки - ключ -g.

Обычно ошибка возникает не в самом последнем вызове, а где-то в предыдущих, где портится память, но программа заваливается не сразу.

Comment: добавил, что еще нужно?